Time difference between `devtools::test()` and `devtools::check()`
I have difficulties trying to decrease the time spent to check my package, srnadiff (for reproducibility, you can get the GitHub repo from https://github.com/mzytnicki/srnadiff, on the devel branch).
I tried to reduce the tests to 2 files (for reproducibility: test_annotation.R and test_pvalues.R).
When I use devtools::check(), the "checking tests" step takes 29 minutes.  With all the files, it takes more than one hour. Same goes with R CMD check on the built package. On the BioC check platform, it reaches the time limit.
When I use devtools::test(), the same tests takes 8 seconds.
Now, on the computer of my colleague, trying to reproduce the BioC environment variables, the whole devtools::check takes a few minutes.
I am puzzled by the discrepancy, and would like to reduce this time.
Does anyone have a suggestion about how I could proceed?
I used profvis with the command
p <- profvis::profvis({foo <- devtools::check()})

It seems that most of the time is spent on .Call (with no other sub-function called), and I cannot interpret this.
I thank you very much for your help.

I am pretty sure devtools::check() starts a separate process to run R CMD check, so you won't get any useful profiling information from it.  Try tools:::.check_packages("path_to_tarball") if you want to see where time is being spent.
